# Magento 2 products positioning in category

Tags: category-products, magento2.3.1, position

I have converted my Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3.1. In Magento 1.9, the products are listed by the position as the following orders 0,1,2,3...10.. and so on. But when I check in Magento 2.3.1 site, all products are listed opposite, they are now listed in the order 10,9,8,7...2,1. How can I get products to be display by position as 0,1,2,3,4 in category page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this url, for after upgrade facing this issue.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15627

i hope its work for you.

Comment: I can see in the post that the issue exist before 2.3.0, and I'm using 2.3.1.